# Starting appium server through Java

Tags: java, macos, shell, terminal, appium

I am using MAC terminal to start appium server. In terminal I have executed command `appium &` to start the server which is working.

I have installed appium server through terminal using `npm -g install appium`

However when I am trying to execute the same code using Java then server is not starting.

Code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","appium &"})
```

Error:
No such file or directory.

I have also tried to create shell script with **appium** command. When I invoke the shell script through Java, it says that command not found.

Code to invoke shell script command.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c","sh appium.sh"})
```

On invoking in Java, it gives error "appium.sh:Error on line1 - appium command not found"

When I invoked the same shell script through the terminal, appium server started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for Starting appium server using java code and use service_url while intializing appium **driver** .Example is taken from [THIS POST](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/01/how-to-start-appium-server-using-java.html)

```
import java.io.File;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class AppiumServerStartStop {

    static String Appium_Node_Path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node.exe";
    static String Appium_JS_Path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\appium.js";
    static AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    static String service_url;

    public static void appiumStart() throws Exception{
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().
                usingPort(2856).usingDriverExecutable(new File(Appium_Node_Path)).
                withAppiumJS(new File(Appium_JS_Path)));
        service.start();
        Thread.sleep(25000);
        service_url = service.getUrl().toString();
    }

    public static void appiumStop() throws Exception{
        service.stop();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void startAppiumServer() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String appiumNodeFilePath = APPIUM_NODE_FILE_PATH;
        final String appiumJavaScriptServerFile = APPIUM_JAVA_SCRIPT_SERVER_FILE_PATH;
        final String appiumServerPortNumber = APPIUM_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER;
        final String appiumServerConfigurations = "--no-reset --local-timezone --port "+ appiumServerPortNumber+ " -bp "+(Integer.parseInt(appiumServerPortNumber)+1);
        (new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                String startCommand ="\"" + appiumNodeFilePath + "\" \""+ appiumJavaScriptServerFile + "\" "+ appiumServerConfigurations;
                System.out.println("Server start command: "+startCommand);
                executeCommand(startCommand);
            }
        }).start(); 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(25000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private static void executeCommand(String command) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            System.out.println("Appium Server Output Logs:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("Appium Server Error Logs:\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

APPIUM_NODE_FILE_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe";
   APPIUM_JAVA_SCRIPT_SERVER_FILE_PATH="C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to learn how it should be implemented, check appium-java-client [AppiumDriverLocalService](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/cb8a80e44087f930bd5ec7f158e24ba9d93074aa/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/service/local/AppiumDriverLocalService.java) class.

And since you are using java in most cases its better to use `AppiumDriverLocalService` instead implementing your own solution:

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.
  buildDefaultService();
service.start() // to start appium server
...
service.getUrl() // to get URL of running server
...
service.isRunning() // to check if appium server is alive
...
service.stop() // to stop appium server
```